# Why am I getting MissingMethodInvocationException?

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I've a service that invokes a DAO through Spring, so now I'm trying to do some testing using mock. Here is my context:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd" 
        default-autowire="byName">

    <import resource="classpath*:invoice-core-config-test.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:invoice-cfd-config.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath*:invoice-almacenaje-config.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath*:invoice-firmadigital-config.xml" />
    <bean id="comprobanteServiceMock" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.Class"
            value="com.praxis.fact.core.entity.Comprobante" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And here is my service class:

```
public class ComprobanteServiceImpl implements ComprobanteService {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ComprobanteServiceImpl.class);

    /**
     * Dao de comprobantes que se va a utilizar para el servicio.
     */
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("comprobanteDao")
    private ComprobanteDao comprobanteDao;


    @Override
    public List<MedioGeneracion> getMediosGeneracion() throws BusinessException {
        try {
            if (comprobanteDao == null) {           
                ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new 
                ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:invoice-core-config-test.xml");
                comprobanteDao = (ComprobanteDao) ctx.getBean("comprobanteDao");
            }           
            return comprobanteDao.getMediosGeneracion();
        } catch (Exception daoExc) {
            throw new BusinessException(CodigoError.ERROR_NEGOCIO, "Error al obtener los medios de generacion", daoExc);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally here is my testing method:

```
@Test
public void testSalvarComprobanteConMedioGeneracion() {
    try {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new 
                ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:context.xml");
        this.comprobanteTestBean = (Comprobante) ctx.getBean("comprobanteTestBean");
        this.comprobanteService = (ComprobanteService)ctx.getBean("comprobanteService");
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        when(comprobanteService.saveComprobante(comprobanteTestBean)).thenReturn(obtenerRespuesta());
    } catch (BusinessException e) {
        logger.error("Error al iniciar el setup() de la prueba", e.getMessage());
    } catch (InitializationError e) {
        logger.error("Ejecuta con: -DfactElectronica.home=C:/tmp");
    }   
} 

private Long obtenerRespuesta() {
    System.out.println("obtenerRespuesta"); 
    return new Long(1);
}
```

So when I run my test I´m getting:
    org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.

```
at com.praxis.fact.cfd.business.impl.ComprobanteServiceImplTests.testSalvarComprobanteConMedioGeneracion(ComprobanteServiceImplTests.java:242)
```

Why is that error happening?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only object that is a mock is an instance of Comprobante. However, your when() method surrounds a call to an instance of ComprobanteService. The ComprobanteService object needs to be a mock, that is what the error message means.

Note that for this test the Comprobante object does NOT need to be a mock, although you may want to mock it for other tests.

Also, your use of MockitoAnnotations.initMocks() is unnecessary, as you aren't using the annotations.

Comment: one of your comments made me realize that I was missing the mock annotation on Comprobante Thanks.